# Visibility of class variables

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization, thread-safety

Static variables can be updated within regular members of a class. Assuming a situation in which we have `private static int counter;` correspondingly `public void countMore(){counter++;}`. now if we have two threads of 2 different objects of the same class, and the method`countMore()` is invoked on those two objects, how can we guarantee visibility of the class-static variable **counter**?

**Edit:**

Notice:

when we have two threads

```
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(new SomeClass()) 
 Thread thread2 = new Thread(new SomeClass())
 thread1.start();
 thread2.start();
```

synchronizing the instance method countMore() would not help in this regard.

Comment: How do you mean "visibility"? The variable will always be visible, but you will get problems determining/changing the value due to concurrency.

Comment: Synchronization (both here, and wherever you read the variable), or `AtomicInteger`. This is Java concurrency 101; I suggest you obtain and digest Java Concurrency In Practice.

Comment: Synchronize the `countMore()` or use `AtomicInteger`. This must be a duplicate though.

Comment: volatile also guarantees the visibility, but it does not make the ++ operation atomic, so you might lose increments.

Comment: @glee8e careful: synchronizing `countMore()` (as in just adding `synchronized` to the method signature) won't help because it's an instance method. It's not clear whether this is what you are advocating, but it could be interpreted in that way.

Comment: Guys^^.., thx for your cooperation.., but as far as I know the lock is per object.., so even using synchronized keyword (block) would not help here (i.e both threads entering the block at the same time) because we have 2 -different objects..,

Comment: @ProfessPhysics you can add a `private static final Object counterLock = new Object()`, and synchronize on that.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice it was an instance method and typically it should be a static one.

Comment: @AndyTurner thx for your help man.., so I basically asked this because as far as I know everything else including instance variables and local variables would be copied for different objects.., but in case of static.., then it is kinda of saying it is shared and can be accessed from different objects..., I still don't know why some people got angry.., I guess it is about misunderstanding the question!

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions with glue code

```
//You should make the counter fiels private so noone can ignore the synchronized

//Solution 1 synchronized
private static int counter;

static synchronized void countMore(){
    counter++;
}

static synchronized int getCount(){
    return counter;
}

//Solution 2 Atomics
private static AtomicInteger acounter;

static void acountMore(){
    acounter.addAndGet(1);
}

static int getaCount(){
    return acounter.get();
}
```

Comment: Note: the `AtomicInteger` should be `final` (and assigned); and there may be reasons why these methods were not static in the first place (e.g. they are designed to be overridden), so don't assume you can just make them `static`. Also, you can use `acounter.incrementAndGet()` (or `getAndIncrement()`) rather than having to specify the 1.